# How to add an Ajax jQuery code, that returns a row from a PHP file [database] and then change the value of input text?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, mysql

This is a code in [PHP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PHP) which is fetching a record from a database:

```
<?php
    include("dbconn.inc");
    $data = mysql_query(
              "SELECT `subtitle`, `mian-title`, `page_num`, `note_path`, `flash_path`
              FROM `main-page`
              WHERE `page_num` =".$r." LIMIT 1";
    echo $data;
    if (mysql_num_rows($data) == 0) {
        echo "No rows found, nothing to print so am exiting";
        exit;
    }
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($data)) {
        echo $row['page_num'];
    }
    include("close.php");
?>
```

And this is the HTML:

```
<form method="post" action="data.php">
    <input name="Button1" type="submit" value="&lt;&lt;" />
    <input name="test" style="width: 31px; height: 23px" type="text" /> // this is a value of page_num in DB.
    <input name="Button2" type="submit" value="&gt;&gt;" >
</form>
```

I want to add Ajax code to retrieve the record from PHP code, and then change the input values depends on returned data and also want to preventing the page from refreshing!

Comment: $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url:   'data.php',
                    data:{'page_num':num
                    },
                    success:function(data){
                     // i don't know what to make her with the different data from php 
                          }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use [jQuery](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JQuery) to call the function, and push the information into the `div`, pushing the old information out. (If this is what you mean. Otherwise, you just put it into another `div`). This would be something like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    // jQuery document

    $(document).ready(function(){
        function getInfo() {
            $.get('yourfile.php', function(data) {
                $('#yourdiv').html(data);
            });

</script>
```

This should do the trick. If it doesn't, you can always add a `$.ajax` instead of `$.get`.

```
$("#inputid).click(function(){
    if ('value' == this button){
        $.get('yourcontentsfile.php', function(data){
            $('#contentthatmustchangediv').html(data);
        }
        if('value' == the other one){
            $.get('yourcontentsfile.php', function(data){
                $('#contentthatmustchangediv').html(data);
            }
        });
```

I'm not entirely sure this code will work 100%. You might have to change one or two things. But the idea should be right.

(I'm not sure if you've noticed, but you've typed "mian-title". It might be a typo.)

Comment: the problem that i can pass a data from php to AJAX,but i can't deal with it ?? 
i want to change the value of input:"test" ,at each time i click on button1 or button2

Comment: hmmm in that case you have to make radio buttons of  "test". 
These buttons you give values, and you make a jquery function that checks which one is selected. On different selections you make different functions. you have to use an on click function for this.
If you need an example code let me know and i'll edit my answer.

Comment: nop ..what i want,i wanna to change the content of page [flash,note,title],depends on the page number which is on input:"test"
and the data will retrieve from MYsQL

Comment: ohhh sorry.

In that case you make the content you want, and you use my example code to push it into the "content" div. And instead of document ready you make a function to respond to the button on with ".click" .
You also have to give your input an ID.
So:
$("#inputid).click(function(){
if (#inputid == this button) $.get('yourcontentsfile.php', function(data){
$('#contentthatmustchangediv').html(data);
});

And let me just add this to the answer for sake of codes

Answer (score 1):

You need to give your input an id. And when you're trying to set a value in an input, you need to use `.val()`:

```
<script>
    $(function() {
        $.get('yourfile.php', function(data) {
            $('#test').val(data);
        });
    });
</script>
</head>
    <body>

    <form method="post" action="data.php">
        <input name="Button1" type="submit" value="&lt;&lt;" />
        <input id="test" name="test" style="width: 31px; height: 23px" type="text" /> // This is a value of page_num in the database.
        <input name="Button2" type="submit" value="&gt;&gt;" >
</form>
```

If you're trying to stop the form from submitting then you need to:

1. Give the form an id attribute.
2. Capture the `.submit()` event
3. Return false

This will encode an array as [JSON](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON):

```
<?php
    $arr = array('a' => 1, 'b' => 2, 'c' => 3, 'd' => 4, 'e' => 5);
    echo json_encode($arr);
?>
```

Using [Firebug](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Firebug_%28software%29) in Firefox (on the console tab), you will see this:

```
{"a":1,"b":2,"c":3,"d":4,"e":5}
```

Now in [jQuery](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JQuery), instead of `.get()`, use `.getJSON()`.

Then inside the function instead of

```
    $('#test').val(data);
```

use

```
$('#test').val(data.a);
```

Comment: put the data is compose of many thing .. the SQL statement will retrieve a 4 value .. ??

Comment: i would return json from the php script and then have the jquery assign the json values to the form inputs

Comment: {how to do that ? give me a sentence

Comment: i make this in JQuery :

<script type="text/javascript" >
'$(function(){    
    $('#submit').submit(function(event){
 $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'data.php',
   // data: $('input:radio[name=num]').val(),
      
        success: function(data){
            alert(data);
             var split_data=data.split("|");
                    $("#itemdesc").val(split_data[0]);
                    $("#supitem").val(split_data[1]);
                    $("#smalluom").val(split_data[2]);
//return false; 
 },
  error: function(e, ts, et) { alert(ts) }
 });   
 event.preventDefault(); });
    });'

Comment: and this in php,but it doesn't work :( :
 `while($dispresult=mysql_fetch_array($data)){
                         echo $dispresult['subtitle'] . "|";
                         echo $dispresult['mian-title'] . "|";
                         echo $dispresult['page_num'];
            }`

Comment: so tackle one thing at a time. is the php outputting like you want it to? it seems like you spelled maintitle incorrectly. You should probably update your question with your current status.